# Exporting the first 1000 and last 1000 records in MongoDB to JSON

Tags: mongodb

I need to take the first 1000 and last 1000 records from my mongo collection and export them to json. However since the export utility is so limited, and my record set has millions of records, this isn't done easily. I can't really seem to find a way to create the query string for this particular function.

Comment: I tried mongoexport -q "{query:{num: {\$lt:1000}},orderBy : {num:1}}"

Comment: You cannot do this with the export functions because atm they only accept one query, you need two queries to do this

Comment: yeah that is fine, I can do the first 1000 in a query and the last 1000 in another query.

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 2):

count = `db.collection.count()` for total count
first 1000 = `db.collection.find().limit(100)` for the first 1000
last 1000 = `db.collection.find().skip(count-1000).limit(1000)` for the last 1000

then just join results and serialize to json

Comment: the problem is I want to be able to do this through the export utility.

Answer (score 1):

```
mongoexport --uri='mongodb+srv://..../DBNAME' --collection='COLLECTION_NAME' --query='{FIELD_NAME: {EXPRESSION}}' --limit=100 --skip=1000 --out='FILENAME.json'
```